# How to get this click and run effect in linux?

Tags: c, windows, linux

I have a c program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  printf("Hello");
}
```

**On Windows:**

I compile that program on windows and get **a.exe**

Now when I `double-click` on **a.exe**

Command windows opens

**a.exe** is run

and automatically close that windows.

To overcome this i have two solution

1>  Create a `batch` file with the following content:

```
a.exe
pause
```

2> or add `getch()` function in my code

**On LINUX**

Now i want the same thing to happen in linux

I have compiled that program on linux get **a.out** and whenever i click on that nothing happens?

I have made one shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

./a.out &

pause
```

and run that script by clicking on it but still nothing happened?

---

Comment: Real Linux programmers don't have mice ;-)

Comment: @Mr.32 - The program prints an output to STDOUT. To watch STDOUT, you need a terminal. Open up a terminal, make sure you're in the right directory, and execute it with `./a.out`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you're not seeing is that it won't open in anything at all; the program will just execute quietly in the background.

To make the output visible, you'll need to make a shell script to run the program in a terminal, which can be as simple as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -x "`dirname \"$0\"`"/a.out
```

Mark the script as executable, and now you should be able to double-click it and see your program open in a terminal window.  Note that tying the program to a particular terminal emulator (like `gnome-terminal`) is probably a bad idea, and you should rethink why you want this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Linux doesn't distinct between terminal and GUI applications.

What you need to do is to actually configure the program to run in a terminal, or just run a terminal and execute the program in it.

Comment: how can i configure the program to run a terminal?

Comment: @Mr.32 I'm pretty sure that you can do that through the properties menu (through right click). But there is a possibility that you would actually have to create a .desktop file. http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html